# full width and height fixed slideshow images (<img>) responsive and always centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

so i have a slideshow with images that are NOT background images, they are inline img tags, and i would like the slideshow to look like on this template: http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/52603.html

i need it to be responsive, full width and height, and always horizontally and vertically centered, cropping the same amount from the top as from the bottom and from the right as from the left.

i've been researching and mostly found answers for background images. if this were a background image i would know how to do it....

i can use css and jquery, but preferably only css.

this is the html:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" id="cycle-slideshow">
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="cycle-slide cycle-sentinel">
    <img src="http://teste.boleiafacil.com/img/empresa_teste__home_1.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <span class="cycle-prev">&lt;</span>
  <span class="cycle-next">&gt;</span>
  <span class="cycle-pager"><span class="">•</span><span class="">•</span><span class="cycle-pager-active">•</span></span>
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="cycle-slide">
    <img src="http://teste.boleiafacil.com/img/empresa_teste__home_1.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="cycle-slide">
    <img src="http://teste.boleiafacil.com/img/empresa_teste__home_2.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="cycle-slide cycle-slide-active">
    <img src="http://teste.boleiafacil.com/img/empresa_teste__home_3.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a bootstrap carousel?

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

It's pratictical and has a lot of background documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Using images instead of backgrounds there's no guarantee you'll never get letterboxing - you can get close using something like this though!

```
   .cycle-slide{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     overflow: hidden;
   }
   .cycle-slide img{
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     max-height: 100%;
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
   }
```